# How to load debug symbols for the whole OVMF UEFI image in gdb?

Tags: debugging, gdb, qemu, uefi, edk2

I am trying to debug a driver in UEFI firmware (OVMF) via gdb as described here:

https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/How-to-debug-OVMF-with-QEMU-using-GDB

It works well, but I discovered that just having debug symbols for my driver is not enough. I also need debug symbols for the whole OVMF image to properly see what's going on. I have a lot of .debug files after OVMF is built with edk2, but I don't understand which ones I need to load into gdb, and what addresses I should use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some instructions involving [DebugPkg](https://github.com/andreiw/andreiw-wip/tree/master/uefi/DebugPkg), but I couldn't make `gdb_uefi.py` work no matter what. It always failed to locate `EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE_POINTER`.

In the end, I ended up writing my own script, which implements gdb command that does manage to successfully load all debug symbols. It is probably a worse solution, since it requires a setup: "debug.log" with driver addresses must be present when loading is performed, so you need to run QEMU at least once first. But, this is good enough for me.

My script can be found here:

https://github.com/artem-nefedov/uefi-gdb